# How can we access a surface view class from the xml layout file?

Tags: java, android, xml, surfaceview

Basically, I'm implementing a system where in the view consists of buttons and a surface view. This surface view is defined programmatically inside the class of the main activity. Now I need to add this as part of the xml file as it's own tag.

The current xml code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/downbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/upbutton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Down" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rightbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/leftbutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/upbutton"
        android:text="Right" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/leftbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/downbutton"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/upbutton"
        android:text="Left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upbutton"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rightbutton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Up" />

    <com.example.gui.GridSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/gridsurfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#cbfff4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, "com.example.gui.GridSurfaceView" refers to the surface view class. However, my surface view class has now been placed inside the class of the main activity and cannot be removed (since the surface view class requires some variables from that activity to be accessed). The view appeared fine when the surface view had it's own class but now, this xml is causing some issues. How would I go about changing the xml to include the surface view again?

EDIT - Well, since asked, here is the activity code too. Since the code is too large, i've included the part of the activity that contains the surface view. Note, the name of the main activity is "Robotremote"and the surfaceview is "GridSurfaceView"

```
public class GridSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

SurfaceHolder GridSurfaceHolder;
Thread gridThread = null;
boolean isRunning = false;
Paint paint;
Typeface mFont = Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
Paint red;

public GridSurfaceView(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(14);
    paint.setTypeface(mFont);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    red = new Paint();
    red.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.position));
    GridSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
    gridThread = new Thread(this); //allows for the usage of the run method of     this class. 
    gridThread.start();
}

public void pause(){
    isRunning = false;
    while(true){
        try {
            gridThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
        }
        gridThread = null; 
}

public void resume(){
    isRunning = true;
    gridThread = new Thread(this);
    gridThread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(isRunning){
        if(!GridSurfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        Canvas gridcanvas = GridSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        gridtobedrawn = com.example.gui.Robotremote.getGrid();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        gridcanvas.drawRect(130, 130, 180, 180, paint);
        gridtobedrawn.draw(gridcanvas, paint);
        gridcanvas.drawCircle(xCoord, yCoord, (30*0.45f), red);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Show your activity code too

Comment: My activity code is really, really long.

Comment: i can't see where is the coupling between GridSurfaceView and your activity, why you need GridSurfaceView to be a subclass of Robotremote activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you should do to overcome this problem :

Define an listener interface in your custom view, and define a listener setter.
and in you activity's onCreate method pull the view , cast it to GridSurfaceView and add to it an anonym class implementing your interface listener (like setOnCLickListener for a button)

and in the implementation of the interface you can use any of the fields of the activity

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT** 
Decoupling your GridSurfaceView using a listener to inject xCoord and yCoord into your view , allowing your GridSurfaceView to be separate from you Activity :

1. Define an interface in your GridSurfaceView to handle xCoord , yCoord injection :

   ```
   public interface CoordsProvider {
       public double getXCoord();
       public double getYCoord(); // am assuming your xCoord and yCoord are doubles
   }
   ```
2. define a field provider in your GridSurfaceView

   ```
   CoordsProvider provider;
   ```
3. define a setter for your provider in GridSurfaceView

   ```
    public void setCoordsProvider(CoordsProvider p){
         provider = p;
    }
   ```
4. in your run method , instead of directly using xCoords and yCoords, call your coords provider like this :

   ```
   gridcanvas.drawCircle(provider.getXCoord(), provider.getYCoord(), (30*0.45f), red);
   ```
5. Modify your GridSurfaceView constructor so that it can be inflated from an xml. All you have to do is add a parameter to the constructor :

   ```
    public GridSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   ...//same code
   ```
6. put your GridSurfaceView in your xml layout file as you did in your post
7. pull it in the onCreate method of your Activity after setContentView using findViewById :

   ```
    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_id);
       gridSurfaceView = (GridSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gridsurfaceview);

       gridSurfaceView.setCoordsProvider(new CoordsProvider(){
           @Override
           public double getXCoord(){return xCoord;}

           @Override
           public double getYCoord(){return yCoord;}
       });
   ```

Comment: tell me if you need an example

Comment: I'm really new to this. Think of me as a complete newbie if you will. I found it pretty hard to understand a word of what you said. Any chance you could simplify?

Comment: ok i will edit the answer and put on an example, just tell me where in the GridSurfaceView code you used the fact that it's a subclass of an activity, i can't see why it's not a separate class ,

Comment: Couple of places within the run() method.
1 - gridtobedrawn = com.example.gui.Robotremote.getGrid();
Here, I use the method called getGrid() present in the main class. 

2 - gridcanvas.drawCircle(xCoord, yCoord, (30*0.45f), red);

Here, the values of xCoord and yCoord are updated based on buttons pressed and calculations done inside the main activity.

Comment: in the first place you don't need your view to be a subclass, because it's a call of a static method getGrid is static, you can call it from the outside if it's not private, 
as for the second place, yes you have a problem, xCoord and yCoord are fields of the Activity class, so am going to modifiy your code to show you a solution for it

Comment: Thanks heaps. If there's any other information you'd like me to provide for the main class/activity, you can let me know.

Comment: still writing the answer , almost finished :)

Comment: Will do. :) Thanks a lot for the help! I don't use this site much, what should I do to add your reputation?

Comment: Just read your code. I'm going to try this now. Would this mean that I need to keep my surfaceview class in a separate class of its own instead of in an inner class?

Too low of a reputation to upvote it. Did validate it though.

Comment: Yes this is the goal of all the steps above, that way you can put it in your xml layout and use it like any other view(Buttons, EditTexts, ...)

Comment: if you practice, in a few months you will be a genius too

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a custom view when it's placed as an inner class. Think of it that it has to be independent, and to instantiate the custom view it will have to instantiate the entire Activity.

I would recommend having a FrameLayout or ViewStub placeholder in the XML, and inflating the custom view programmatically.

Comment: Can you please elaborate FrameLayout?

Comment: FrameLayout is a ViewGroup that can hold as a child your SurfaceView. That way, you can define the exact location and other parameters of you FrameLayout to be located correctly in the XML, and then inflate your SurfaceView without worrying about his LayoutParams.